# instantiate or initialize when using a new class?

Tags: c#, comments

my question is rather a matter of English language. For proper commenting my code I want to know when you do for example the following code, what comment you can write for it?

```
public class TestClass
{
    public double volt {get; set;}
    public double curr {get; set:}
}
```

Somewhere else in the same namespace

```
public class AnotherTest
{
    TestClass test;

    public AnotherTest(TestClass test)
    {
       this.test = new TestClass(); //how to comment this?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you comment that?  It's self explanatory?  Also, should it not be this.test = test, or are you doing something else with the constructor parameter?

Comment: Well I give up commenting that line, can you tell me what is the most professional way to name what is happening in that line? Since I saw different names for it.

Comment: use instantiate when you are allocation memory as in this case when you are creating a new object. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330767/what-is-the-difference-between-instantiated-and-initialized

Comment: In you case, you are instantiating the object.  However, I think your line of code should read this.test = test.  In that case you are initialising, as more than likely, the TestClass object that you are passing into the constructor would already have been instantiated else where.  As a base rule, instantiation is where you create the object, initialisation is where you give it some value.

Comment: The best advice for how to comment this line is to not comment it. Take a look at [Comment Only What the Code Cannot Say](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Comment_Only_What_the_Code_Cannot_Say) from *97 Things Every Programmer Should Know*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need comments in the example given. You need better variable names.

Use the following rules to judge the value of a comment:

1. Comment on specific implementation of a piece of logic or business rule or program modification log, or feature change
2. Never comment on language syntax inside the code (as in your case) - The developer should know the syntax
3. Comment on a specific choice of a computing approach such as useing Instr instead of Regex that could result in performance gain
4. Add comments to describe specific usage of variables and methods to avoid unnecessary long names or to clarify the purpose for the reader quickly.
5. Too many comments are useless and harmful sometimes, especially if not maintained.
6. The code is not the only place for comments.
7. If you are working on a project, have some guidelines.